# relation between order and multiplicity

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Could any one tell me  with an example, what is the relation between Order and Multiplicity of a holomorphic function on Riemann Surface,and how this formuale comes?

for example let $p\in X$ be not a pole for $f$, and $f(p)=z_0$ then $f(z)-z_o$ has a simple zero at $p$ so $mult_p(f-f(p))=1$,$ord_p(f-f(p))=ord_p(f)-ord_p(f(p))=1+0?$

Comment: The formula $ord_p(f-g)=ord_p(f)-ord_p(g)$ that you seem to use is false

Answer (score 1):

Let me just quote Rick Miranda's "[Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=qjg6GOQaHNEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)":

> **(Chapter II) Lemma 4.7:** Let $f$ be a meromorphic function on a Riemann surface $X$, with associated holomorphic map $F\colon X \to \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$.
>
> a) If $p \in X$ is a zero of $f$, then $\text{mult}_p(F) = \text{ord}_p(f)$.
>
> b) If $p \in X$ is a pole of $f$, then $\text{mult}_p(F) = -\text{ord}_p(f)$.
>
> c) If $p \in X$ neither a zero nor a pole of $f$, then $\text{mult}_p(F) = \text{ord}_p(f - f(p))$.

I don't have time right now, but perhaps later I'll include a proof and an example.

Comment: I find Miranda's trichotomy artificial: if $p$ is not a pole of $f$, then $\text{mult}_p(F) = \text{ord}_p(f - f(p))$, period. There is no need to artificially  distinguish the cases $f(p)=0$ and $f(p)\neq 0$. In other words, I find it clearer to say that you have  the dichotomy: either b) or else  a)+c). But of course this is a matter of taste and Miranda's book is excellent  anyway, so +1 for your mentioning it.

Comment: How to prove the relation between order and multiplicity?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626800/relation-between-order-and-multiplicity-of-a-meromorphic-function-on-a-riemann-s

Comment: Please verify this proof.